# The specified type member '' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hi i am getting below error for blow LINQ statement. In sample query i am  trying to find those data which is caller. clientid =  client. clientid AND caller.password = password.

`The specified type member 'CALLER' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

```
 var tempCNum = context.UserName.Split('_')[0];
 var tempCall = context.UserName.Split('_')[1];
var user = db.clients.Join(db.Callers, cl => cl.CLIENTID, ca => ca.CLIENTID,
          (cl, ca) => new { client = cl, Caller = ca }).
          Where(m => m.Caller.CALLER== tempCall && m.Caller.Password== context.Password && m.client.CLIENTNUM== tempCNum).ToList();
```

Property class for client

```
public partial class client
    {
       public client()
        {
            this.Callers = new HashSet<Caller>();
        }

        public int CLIENTID { get; set; }
        public string CLIENTNUM { get; set; }
        public string CONTACT { get; set; }
}


public partial class Caller
    {
         public int CLIENTID { get; set; }
        public string CALLER1 { get; set; }
        public int CALLERID { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public  string CALLER { get; set; }
}
```

Can you help me fix this issue . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @juharr from context i was setting some values . I have edited  my question. Please take a look

Comment: Your example does not look to be complete. For instance your client has a navigation property for callers initialized that isn't declared. The error implies that "CALLER" is not a mapped property on the Caller class, as in it could be marked as Ignored in the entity configuration. If you have navigation properties available then what you are looking to do should be possible using those rather than explicit joins.